# Wordpress ajax loop refresh on click

Tags: ajax, wordpress, loops

I display a random post loop on a page. I'd like to put a "refresh" link to refresh the content of the loop via ajax.

Is this possible?

This is my loop:

```
            <ul id="content-inner" class="thumb-grid clearfix">
            <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=20&orderby=rand'); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $my_image_url = get('thumbnail'); ?>" alt="" />
                        <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                        <span class="feat"><?php $articletags = strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('',', ',''));echo $articletags;?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the random post code in a div (if you haven't already), and refresh the contents of that div with JQuery...

Something like this should work (but I haven't had time to test)...

In the Head of your page reference JQuery, then use JQuery.Ready to load the first random post (for initial page load):

```
<head>

<script> /*...reference JQuery...*/ </script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#randomdiv").html("<?php getRandomPost() ?>");
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
 ....

<div id="randomdiv">[placeholder text]</div>
<a id="refresh" href="#">click</a>

<!-- Then for the REFRESH:
make sure this script occurs AFTER your div (above) -->
<script> 
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#randomdiv").html("<?php getRandomPost() ?>");
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>

</body>
```

So put your entire loop code in a function called getRandomPost() (or something) and place it in your wordpress "functions.php" file..., then just call "$("#randomdiv").html("");" in the head of your page for initial load, then in the body as I've shown for the refresh...

Comment: Hi, thxs - ive attached the loop i used, im not sure it i can adapt or can't use the code u posted  with it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I seem to get the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function query_posts()" kick back when i hit the refresh link.... any ideas ?

Comment: Query_posts is a WordPress method so makesure my script example that is in the head appears after WordPress initialization stuff... most likely you will be editing header.PHP.

Comment: Doesn't seem too like it mate. Everything i try kicks back the error above.

Comment: Ok now plan- simply create a new function for your loop code in your theme's functions.php file. Call it getRandomPost() and then you can reference it from your code as simple php call... I'll update my answer above...